# JPA "The attribute matching the ID class attribute xxxxxxx does not have the correct type int"

Tags: java, jpa, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

I have a Java Entity Class "Portfolio.java", which has a composite primary key(portfolio_id, portfolio_name). I used @IdClass to create the composite primary key. and those two are the only instances in the class.

I have another class "Application.java", also with composite primary key(application_id,portfolio_id). I have again used @IdClass to create composite primary key.

Now, application_id is a instance of "Application.java" class, whereas portfolio_id is a foreign key to corresponding instance in "Portfolio.java" class.

Does anyone have any idea as how to implement this using Java?

I have tried doing the following,

**PortfolioPK.java :**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class PortfolioPK implements Serializable {

public int portfolio_id;
public int portfolio_name;

public PortfolioPK() {
    super();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return super.equals(obj);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode();
}

.....
}
```

**Portfolio.java :**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PortfolioPK.class)
public class Portfolio {

@Id
private int portfolio_id;
@Id
private int portfolio_name;

.....
}
```

**ApplicationPK.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ApplicationPK  implements Serializable {

public int application_id;
public int portfolio_id;
public int portfolio_name;

public ApplicationPK() {
    super();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return super.equals(obj);
}

.....
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ApplicationPK.class)
public class Application {

@Id
private int application_id;
private String application_name;
private String app_properties;

@Id
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
@JoinColumn(name="portfolio_id", referencedColumnName="portfolio_id")
private Portfolio portfolio_id;

.....
}
```

So, now im getting an error at the @IdClass declaration in "Application.java". the error is, "The attribute matching the ID class attribute portfolio_id does not have the correct type int"

Is this a correct implementation? or should it be done in a different way?

Thanks for any help ! :)

Comment: Application field "portfolio_id" should be called "portfolio" and should have 2 columns (since you have to refer to a Portfolio using 2 Id columns)

Answer (score 2):

This is a "derived identity" - the ID of `Portfolio` is part of the ID of the `Application` and there is a many-to-one relationship between them. To map that correctly, you need to have a property of type `PortfolioPK` in `ApplicationPK` with the same name as the relationship property in `Application`. So:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ApplicationPK.class)
public class Application {

    @Id
    private int application_id;
    // No fields referring to Portfolio ID fields

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="portfolio_id", referencedColumnName="portfolio_id")
    private Portfolio portfolio; // name it simply "portfolio"

    // ...
}

public class ApplicationPK  implements Serializable {

    public int application_id; // name matches the field in Application
    public PortfolioPK portfolio; // name matches the relationship field in Application

    // ...
}
```

See section *"2.4.1 Primary Keys Corresponding to Derived Identities"* of the [JPA 2.1 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) for more details and examples (*Example 2* is your case).